# Scala Play apps without a web UI?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have been writing Scala apps lately, and for those requiring Web UIs, the Play framework has been fantastic, but I'm struggling to define a sensible library stack for back-end apps without UI. Play provides two very useful components for these UI-less apps: good JSON support and convenient app packaging via 'sbt stage'. But it also brings a lot of unused baggage I would rather trim off these back-end apps.

I know JSON support in the Scala standard library is essentially gone, and that options like Jackson/Jerkson or Argonaut exist, but I am hoping to use a unified approach across applications rather than dealing with multiple libraries for identical purposes. Also I know other packaging plugins exist for sbt, but this poses the same problem.

Does it make sense to use Play for apps without a Web UI? Are folks actually doing this out there? If so, how can I configure Play to work in this way? (e.g. not start the HTTP listener on :9000).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Write more what is your need. Do you need middleware application? How this app will communicate with others?

Comment: For JSON-only endpoints I would go with spray

Comment: You can use the `play-json` library outside of Play.

Comment: `sbt-assembly` can handle the packaging stuff https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: A web UI can be a very nice thing to keep around for a `/health` page, admin console etc. Just don't expose it to your clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, Play works great with REST apps as does Spray (soon to be Akka HTTP). Spray will use fewer resources but Play is not particularly large either.

It comes down to preference. Use Play if you prefer to write programs in a Play style (declarative, fast dev cycle) and use Spray (Akka HTTP) if you prefer more control and want to base your code around actors (message passing, supervision).

Both Play and Spray each have their own JSON libraries which can be used standalone, but unfortunately the libraries are not interchangable with each other.

I don't understand your question about packaging plugins, but Play uses [sbt-native-packager](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/).

To configure an HTTP port in Play use `-Dhttp.port=1234`. See
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration for all the details.

Comment: Choose Play where productivity dominates your decision making, and Spray/akka-http where performance and flexibility are required.